# Simplification of code (need help to refine the title of this question ... )

Tags: haskell

I don't have a name for what I'm looking for... (I will update the title of this question as soon as I have it...).

Here is the context :

```
data EventStoreMicroService = EventStoreMicroService {
                                    urlHost :: String,
                                    port :: Int,
                                    username :: ByteString,
                                    password :: ByteString}

getCredentials :: EventStoreMicroService -> EventStore.Credentials
getCredentials EventStoreMicroService {username,password} = EventStore.credentials username password

getConnectionType :: EventStoreMicroService -> EventStore.ConnectionType
getConnectionType EventStoreMicroService {urlHost,port} = (EventStore.Static urlHost port)

getEventStoreSettings :: EventStoreMicroService -> EventStore.Settings
getEventStoreSettings service = EventStore.defaultSettings
```

I have this function :

```
connect :: Settings -> ConnectionType -> IO Connection
```

And this is what I'm doing so far :

```
let microservice = EventStoreMicroService {
      urlHost = "127.3.4.5",
      port = 2000,
      username = "xxxx",
      password = "yyy"}
    eventStoreSettings = getEventStoreSettings microservice
    eventStoreConnectionType = getConnectionType microservice

connect eventStoreSettings eventStoreConnectionType
```

I'm looking for a magical function (I named it 'from') that will be able to express it that way :

```
let microservice = EventStoreMicroService {
      urlHost = "127.3.4.5",
      port = 2000,
      username = "xxxx",
      password = "yyy"}
    eventStoreSettings = getEventStoreSettings microservice
    eventStoreConnectionType = getConnectionType microservice

connect $ from microservice getEventStoreSettings getConnectionType
```

basically it applies 2 functions to a data type that return let say (a,b) and feed this tuple to a function connect...

Comment: I'm curious as to why you are implementing microservices in haskell. Microservices are a solution to a problem that haskell doesn't have.

Comment: The question is what do you consider to be a Microservice ? @MichaelLitchard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that you don't really need a magical function. It would probably be clearer to just use the existing `Applicative` instance for functions.

```
data EventStoreMicroService = EventStoreMicroService {
                                urlHost :: String,
                                port :: Int,
                                username :: ByteString,
                                password :: ByteString}

getCredentials :: EventStoreMicroService -> EventStore.Credentials
getCredentials = EventStore.Credentials <$> username <*> password

getConnectionType :: EventStoreMicroService -> EventStore.ConnectionType
getConnectionType = EventStore.Static <$> urlHost <*> port

getEventStoreSettings :: EventStoreMicroService -> EventStore.Settings
getEventStoreSettings _ = EventStore.defaultSettings
-- or getEventStoreSettings = const EventStore.defaultSettings
```

Then

```
let microservice = EventStoreMicroService { urlHost = "127.3.4.5"
                                          , port = 2000
                                          , username = "xxxx"
                                          , password = "yyy"
                                          }    
(connect <$> getEventStoreSettings <*> getConnectionType) microservice
-- or skip getEventStoreSettings, and use defaultSettings directly
-- connect EventStore.defaultSettings (getConnectionType microservice)
```

Answer (score 2):

So I think you're after something like this?

```
from :: a -> (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> (b, b)
from a f g = (f a, g a)
```

And then you can use it like this:

```
uncurry connect $ from microservice getEventStoreSettings getConnectionType
```

I'm sure something like this `from` probably exists in the standard library, but I can't find anything in a quick search on Hoogle.

EDIT: as @WillNess points out in the comments, this can be improved in a couple of ways.

First, my version of `from` above can be simplified as `from a f g = (f &&& g) a`.

Second, you can avoid the need for `uncurry` by defining a more general version of `from`:

```
from' :: (b -> b -> c) -> a -> (a -> b) -> (a -> b) -> c
from' c a f g = c (f a) (g a)
```

allowing one to do simply:

```
from' connect  microservice getEventStoreSettings getConnectionType
```

Comment: `from a f g = (f &&& g) a`. But then the `uncurry` is unavoidable this way. Perhaps, simply define `from c a f g = c (f a) (g a) = (c . f <*> g) a`.

Comment: Thanks, I forgot about the Arrow methods :) And I was going off the OP's suggestion to have `from` return a pair, which of course makes `uncurry` unavoidable. Your version definitely looks better though, feel free to post it as an answer as I can't claim any credit.

Comment: By SO rules it is perfectly OK to include it in your answer while providing attribution (e.g. "as [Will Ness](...user link...) mentions in the comments, ..." etc., and you are welcome to do it. :)

Comment: Thanks, have done so. (I've left out the rewriting as `(c . f <*> g) a` though, mainly because I'm struggling to understand it myself. Which instance of Applicative is being used here?)

Comment: functions'. since `.` works with functions, `c . f` is a fucntion, hence that. besides, I just use it as a pointfree shortcut, `(f <*> g) x = f x (g x)` (a.k.a. S combinator), without thinking of applicatives at all. Same with `(f =<< g) x = f (g x) x` or `join f x = f x x`. Simply use them as convenient combinators, where convenient.